# link not working HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I know its a stupid question, but I've been trying to find what causes the error

I created a site, however, links in content is not working. i know it's somewhere in the css file but i can't find out what

this is the draft, i removed some parts in the main html, but the css are as ease

```js
    var firstreel=new reelslideshow({
     wrapperid: "myreel", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
     dimensions: [750, 550], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
     imagearray: [
      ["images/a.jpg"], //["image_path", "optional_link", "optional_target"]
      ["images/b.jpg"],
      ["images/c.jpg"],
      ["images/d.jpg"],
      ["images/e.jpg"], 
      ["images/f.jpg"],
      ["images/g.jpg"],
      ["images/h.jpg"]  //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
     ],
     displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2000, cycles:2, pauseonmouseover:true},
     orientation: "h", //Valid values: "h" or "v"
     persist: true, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
     slideduration: 300 //transition duration (milliseconds)
    })
```

```css
    body {
     background: url(images/cheeseclothBG.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
     font-family: Avenir !important;
     font-size: 12pt;
     line-height: 20px;
     
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
    
    }
    #header {
     background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
     min-height: 270px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-size: 100%;
    }
    #content {
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: -101px;
     background: #fff;
     z-index:-1;
     position:relative;
    }
    
     
    #img {
     margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #0000ff;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #img img{
     display: inline;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    
    #desc{
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: normal;
     width: 120px;
     margin: 5px;
    }
    
    
    #container {
     width: 826px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #ccc;
    }
    
    #menu{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    }
    #menu ul{
     margin:0;
     padding:0; 
     line-height:30px;
     margin-left:35px;
     margin-top: 139px;
    }
    
    #menu li{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style:none;
     float:left;
     position:relative;
     background:#fff;
    }
    
    #menu ul li a{
     text-align:center;
     font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
     font-size:12px;
     text-decoration:none;
     height:30px;
     width:150px;
     display:block;
     color:#000;
     margin-left:10px;
     text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;
    }
    
    #menu ul li{
     text-align:center;
     font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
     font-size:12px;
     text-decoration:none;
     height:30px;
     width:150px;
     display:block;
     color:#000;
     
     text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;
    }
    
    #menu ul li ul li a{
     text-align:center;
     margin-left:0px;
     
     
    }
    
    #menu ul li ul{
     margin-top:-5px;
    }
    
    #menu ul li ul li{
     margin-top:-2px;
     margin-left:-35px;
     position:relative;
     z-index:3px;
    }
    #menu ul ul{
     position:absolute;
     visibility:hidden;
     top:32px;
     z-index:10px;
     
    }
    
    #menu ul li:hover ul{
     visibility:visible;
    }
    
    /*******************************/
    #menu li:hover{
     text-decoration:underline;
    
    }
    
    #menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover{
     text-decoration:underline;
     color:#fa9a2a;
     
    }
    
    #menu a:hover{
     color:#fa9a2a;
    }
    
    #menu ul li:hover {
     color:#fa9a2a;
    }
    
    
    
    .clearFloat{
     clear:both;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     
    }
    
    #content p {
     margin: 30px 30px;
    }
    
    #footer {
     background: url(images/footer.jpg);
     min-height: 146px;
     background-size: 100%;
     clear: both;
     
    }
    #fmenu ul {
     padding: 0;
     margin-top: 120px;
     padding-top: 19px;
    }
    #fmenu ul li {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    #fmenu ul li a {
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 1px 14px 0;
     margin-top: 0px;
     color: #000000;
    }
    
    #fmenu p {
     /**margin-top: 120px;
     margin-left: 480px;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 310px;
     font-size: 11px;
     color: #000;
     text-align: right;**/
     
     width:70%;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size: 8pt;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-top:10px;
     display:inline-flex;
     margin-top: 110px;
    }
    
    #fmenu img{
     width:36px;
        height:36px;
    }
    #fmenu ul.social_icons, li.social {
        margin-top:40px;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
        max-width:25%;
        list-style: none;
        float:right;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #mainTxt p{
     margin: 40px 100px;
    }
    
    #overview h2{
     font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
     font-size: 26px;
     
    }
    #overview h1{
     font-family: Impact, !important;
     font-size: 46px;
    }
    #overview h4{
     font-family: Gabriola, !important;
     font-size: 26px;
     color: #e2705a;
     margin-top: -20px;
    }
    #overview h3{
     font-family: Sacramento, !important;
     font-size: 36px;
      margin-top: -20px;
    }
    
    #overview h5{
     font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
     font-size: 21px;
     margin-top: -20px;
     
    }
    
    #reviews table th td{
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #reviews h5{
     font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
     font-size: 18px;
     text-align:center;
    }
    
    #reviews h2{
     font-family: Open Sans Condensed, !important;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #9d9b9b;
     font-size: 26px;
    }
     #reviews h3{
      font-family: Sacramento, !important;
     font-size: 26px;
     font-weight:bold;
     }
    
    #usage h1{
     font-family: Cookie, !important;
     font-size: 46px;
     float:left;
    }
    #usage img{
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
    }
    
    #about p{
     font-family: Georgia, !important;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-style: italic;
     text-align: justify;
    }
    
    #about2 p{
     font-family: Avenir, !important;
     font-size: 16px;
     width:600px;
    }
    
    #about2 ul{
     width:600px;
    }
    
    #about2 li{
     font-family: Avenir, !important;
     font-size: 14px;
     width:600px;
     text-align: left;
    }

**html**


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Our </title>
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
    #myreel{ /*sample CSS for demo*/
    border:15px solid black;
    }
    
    .paginate{
    width: 330px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font:bold 14px Arial;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container"> <!--wrapper-->
     <header id="header">
         <div id="menu" class="menu"> <!--navMenu-->
             <ul>
                    <li><a href="test.php" > HOME </a></li>
                    <li>OUR PRODUCT
        <ul> 
         <li><a href="productOverview.php" > PRODUCT OVERVIEW</a></li>
         <li><a href="usage.php" > CHEESECLOTH USAGE</a></li>
         <li><a href="reviews.php" > PRODUCT REVIEWS </a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li> SUGGESTIONS 
        <ul>
         <li><a href="tips.php" > TIPS and IDEAS </a></li>
         <li><a href="recipe.php" > RECIPES </a></li>
         <li><a href="ideas.php" > SEND US YOUR IDEAS </a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.php" > ABOUT US </a> </li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" > CONTACT US </a> </li>
             </ul> 
       <br class="clearFloat" />
            </div>
    </header>
    
    <section id="content">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/wantBtn.png" style="display:inline; margin: 50px auto; margin-top: 2em;"/> </a>
    
     
     
    
    </section>
    
    <footer id="footer">
     <div id="fmenu" class="fmenu">
      <p>©2015 copyright    |    All Rights Reserved</p>
      <ul class="social_icons">
       <li class="social">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/fb.png" /> </a></li>
       <li class="social">
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/pin.png" /> </a></li>
       <li class="social">
        <a href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/insta.png" /> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
     </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: In the footer > div is not closing in the right order ... It should be footer > div > ul > /ul  > /div > /footer.       But I don't think it affect all links..

Comment: i tested the above and can't reproduce the error - but i don't have your js, is this on a site somewhere?

Comment: It would help to see a JSFiddle or stack snippet that demonstrates it not working.

Comment: Edited it to be in inline fiddle

Comment: the footer is working fine actually, just the content that is keeping me from being redirected from the link. same as header, links works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the `z-index:-1` for `#content`, remove it, also I don't see it for any reason. Your content lie below header tag, disabling link. I hope this helps.

Comment: yup this solved the problem!! can't remember why I  added that there, thanks!!

Comment: yup this solved the problem!! although it affected my drop down links on the menu. any thoughts?